# How to show a histogram of percentages instead of counts using Altair

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, altair

How do I get a histogram of percentages of total instead of a histogram of count using Altair and Pandas?

I have this at the moment:

[image: Histogram of values]

Which I got by doing this:

```
d = {'age': ['12', '32', '43', '54', '32', '32', '12']}
dfTest = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

alt.Chart(dfTest).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X("age:Q", bin=True),
    y='count()',
)
```

Comment: what is `source` here?

Comment: A copy and past error, it should be dfTest (updated with correction)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this with a [Join Aggregate transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/joinaggregate.html) followed by a [Calculate transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/calculate.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

source = pd.DataFrame({'age': ['12', '32', '43', '54', '32', '32', '12']})

alt.Chart(source).transform_joinaggregate(
    total='count(*)'
).transform_calculate(
    pct='1 / datum.total'
).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('age:Q', bin=True),
    alt.Y('sum(pct):Q', axis=alt.Axis(format='%'))
)
```

[image]

---

Edit: this was my initial answer, which is much more complicated:

It's not entirely straightforward, because it requires manually specifying the bin and aggregate transforms currently implied by your encoding, followed by a calculate transform to compute the percentages. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

source = pd.DataFrame({'age': ['12', '32', '43', '54', '32', '32', '12']})

alt.Chart(source).transform_bin(
    ['age_min', 'age_max'],
    field='age',
).transform_aggregate(
    count='count()',
    groupby=['age_min', 'age_max']
).transform_joinaggregate(
    total='sum(count)'  
).transform_calculate(
    pct='datum.count / datum.total'  
).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X("age_min:Q", bin='binned'),
    x2='age_max',
    y=alt.Y('pct:Q', axis=alt.Axis(format='%'))
)
```

[image]

I'm hoping that we'll be able to streamline the transform API in the future.

Comment: How would one modify this to normalise by counts in groups? For example if I am setting the colour based on column C, and i wanted to make sure each histogram (within colour/C) was normalised to the counts in those groups. Would I need to build the bar chart manually?