# Layered normalised histogram per category

Tags: python, data-science, visualization, altair

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56358977/how-to-show-a-histogram-of-percentages-instead-of-counts-using-altair#), I was able to construct a layered histogram that is normalised. However, it seems that the normalisation is done with respect to the total number of samples instead of the total number of samples per category. I was wondering how the normalisation can be done per category using altair?

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

source = pd.DataFrame({'age': ['12', '32', '43', '54', '32', '32', '12','20','44','24'],'gender': ['m','m','f','f','f','m','f','m','f','m']})

alt.Chart(source).transform_joinaggregate(
    total='count(*)'
).transform_calculate(
    pct='1 / datum.total'
).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('age:Q', bin=True),
    alt.Y('sum(pct):Q', axis=alt.Axis(format='%')),
    color='gender'
)
```

[image]

Comment: When you say "per category", do you mean "per age group" or "per gender"?

Comment: @jakevdp per gender

Comment: OK, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to normalize within a particular category, you can compute the total within that category by adding a `groupby` to your aggregate transform:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

source = pd.DataFrame({
    'age': ['12', '32', '43', '54', '32', '32', '12','20','44','24'],
    'gender': ['m','m','f','f','f','m','f','m','f','m']
})

alt.Chart(source).transform_joinaggregate(
    total='count(*)',
    groupby=['gender']
).transform_calculate(
    pct='1 / datum.total'
).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('age:Q', bin=True),
    alt.Y('sum(pct):Q', axis=alt.Axis(format='%')),
    color='gender'
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, I think passing `stack='normalize'` to the y-encoding should work.

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

source = pd.DataFrame({
    'age': ['12', '32', '43', '54', '32', '32', '12','20','44','24'],
    'gender': ['m','m','f','f','f','m','f','m','f','m']
    })

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('age:O', bin=True),
    alt.Y('count()',
          stack='normalize', 
          axis=alt.Axis(title='Group Percentage', format='%'), 
          ),
    color='gender'
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
bins = [10+5*i for i in range(10)]
df_plot = pd.crosstab(source.gender, pd.cut(source.age, bins=bins)).apply(lambda r: r/r.sum(), axis=0).stack().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'perc'})

df_plot['age'] = df_plot['age'].astype(str)

alt.Chart(df_plot).mark_bar().encode(
  x='age:N',
  y=alt.Y('perc:Q', axis=alt.Axis(format='%'), stack=False),
  color='gender:N',
  opacity=alt.value(0.6)
)
```

[image: Altair plot with percentage per group and per bin]

but maybe the question was how to get the percentages of the two groups next to each other ?